# Mock SignalR hub for testing dependent class

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, moq, asp.net-core-signalr

I'm trying to instantiate a class that handles a bunch of functionality, and is constructed using dependency injection. I mock two of my parameters, and the third is an in-memory database context. Now when asserting, it's throwing an error on the `mockClientProxyParticipants.Verify()` line:

> System.NotSupportedException : Invalid verify on an extension method: `proxy => proxy.SendAsync(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>())`

It is virtually impossible to not call the function, and calling `Verify()` with `Times.Never()` as parameter doesn't change anything.

I tried setting up the Linq argument of `Verify()` using normal strings like for `mockClientProxyResults.Verify()`, I tried using `It.Is<string>(s => s == "some string")` and I tried `It.IsAny<string>()`.

I honestly don't understand what's wrong right now. Here's my test code, let me know if you want to see more:

```
var mockHub = new Mock<IHubContext<VoteHub>>();
var mockClients = new Mock<IHubClients>();
var mockClientProxyParticipants = new Mock<IClientProxy>();
var mockClientProxyResults = new Mock<IClientProxy>();

mockClients.Setup(clients => clients.Group("Participants")).Returns(mockClientProxyParticipants.Object);
mockClients.Setup(clients => clients.Group("Results")).Returns(mockClientProxyResults.Object);
mockHub.Setup(hub => hub.Clients).Returns(mockClients.Object);

var activeQuestionManagerMock = new Mock<IActiveQuestionManager>();
activeQuestionManagerMock.Setup(x => x.GetActiveQuestion())
    .Returns(new ActiveQuestionModel(options));

QuestionHandler qm = new QuestionHandler(new VoteDbContext(options), mockHub.Object, activeQuestionManagerMock.Object);

//Act
qm.Ask(question);

//Assert
mockClientProxyParticipants.Verify(proxy => proxy.SendAsync(It.IsAny<string>(/*s => s == "AskQuestion"*/), It.IsAny<string>(/*s => s == qwaJSON*/), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()), Times.Once());
mockClientProxyResults.Verify(proxy => proxy.SendAsync("UpdateCurrentQuestionProgress", It.IsAny<ActiveQuestionModel>(), default(CancellationToken)), Times.Once());
```

Comment: The exception message kind of says it all: *Invalid verify on an **extension method***. Moq does not work with extension methods.

Comment: From the definition of the interface in docs it looks like you will have to mock/verify `SendCoreAsync` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.signalr.iclientproxy?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: Now that you point it out, the message makes sense. It wasn't clear to me that the issue is the fact that it is an extension method from the message alone.. thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out I misunderstood the error message and the issue is that `IClientProxy.SendAsync()` is an extension method, and Moq apparently doesn't like that. It's possible to use `SendCoreAsync()` instead, but you'll always have to pass an array as parameter, even if you want to send just one object or don't want to send any data at all.

credit to NKosi (see question comments)

Comment: Hi, there is a good article talking about it: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1266538/Testing-SignalR-Hubs-in-ASP-NET-Core-2-1